# Merging two rows to one while replacing null values

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Let's say I've got the following database table

```
Name | Nickname | ID
----------------------
Joe    Joey       14
Joe    null       14
```

Now I want to do a select statement that merges these two columns to one while replacing the null values. The result should look like this:

```
Joe, Joey, 14
```

Which sql statement manages this (if it's even possible)?

Comment: should the result really be "Joes" or "Joe"?

Comment: By which column you merge rows? for example, if you will have third row XXX, null, 10. What should your query return?

Comment: It could return an error. I expect only two rows to be found.

Comment: I think you can write query with next condition "Nickname is not null" and it'll return what you want. It only doesn't select rows with null Nicknames.

Comment: @Bernhard, will Joe ever have more than one nickname, and if so how do you want them to be handled?

Answer (score 25):

Simplest solution:

```
SQL> select * from t69
  2  /

NAME       NICKNAME           ID
---------- ---------- ----------
Joe        Joey               14
Joe                           14
Michael                       15
           Mick               15
           Mickey             15

SQL> select max(name) as name
  2         , max(nickname) as nickname
  3         , id
  4  from t69
  5  group by id
  6  /

NAME       NICKNAME           ID
---------- ---------- ----------
Joe        Joey               14
Michael    Mickey             15

SQL>
```

If you have 11gR2 you could use [the new-fangled LISTAGG() function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm) but otherwise it is simple enough to wrap the above statement in a SELECT which concatenates the NAME and NICKNAME columns.

Comment: brilliant answer

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,
the question is not clear.so i am making some assumptions over here.
your output has the first and 3rd columns for both the rows as same.
Only the 2nd field is different.

so u can simply write a select quest

```
select one.name,two.nick_name,one.id from 
(select name,id from your_tb group by name,id) one,
your_tb two 
where two.nickname is not NULL 
and two.name=one.name 
and two.id=one.id;
```

may be we can tune this but i am not good in tuning sql squeries,but this is the way i suppose u need.