# MySQL Query from one table - Select same field twice

Tags: mysql, time, comparison

First of all, I'm a total newbie to MySQL and I fully apologize if I'll ask something which has already been answered under different "terms". I have been searching for a solution to this for over a week now, and I was unable to come up with one, probably because I am not using the right keywords. Please bear with me and my ignorance in this sense :)

I have a table with the following fields:

```
ID            int(11)        NO     PRI     auto_increment
Building      int(11)        YES    MUL     
CounterNo     int(11)        YES    MUL     
ReadingDate   datetime       YES            
StartMeter    int(11)        YES            
EndMeter      int(11)        YES            
CostKw        decimal(10,6)  YES            
Multiplier    smallint(3)    YES
```

I want to make a query, which I would use to populate a comparison line chart, that will return the following:

```
Building | Cons1 | Cons2   | Month
1          1year   ybefore   Month
```

Where the month name would then be used to populate the X axis, and Cons1 would be the consumption for each building for each month in the last year, while Cons2 would be the consumption for each building for each month in the year before.

I have already been playing around, and so far I've gotten to the following one:

```
SELECT  Building,
                        CASE 
            WHEN ReadingDate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
            THEN (EndMeter - StartMeter)
            ELSE NULL
        END
    AS 'Cons1',
            CASE 
            WHEN ReadingDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 Year) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 Year) 
            THEN (EndMeter - StartMeter)
            ELSE NULL
        END
    AS 'Cons2',
CONCAT(
        MONTHNAME (
            tblElectricReadings.ReadingDate
        )
    ) AS MonthRecorded
FROM    tblElectricReadings
WHERE   ReadingDate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
ORDER BY ReadingDate
```

This produces the results I want, but it doesn't "consolidate" (and again, sorry if I am using the wrong words here) Cons1 and Cons2 together, but rather puts a null value to either fields, creating double the records I need. Basically, the query works fine, but it's not the result I want. I would like both Cons1 and Cons2 to be populated with relevant consumption according to each month, so that I can populate the line graph (with 2 lines, 1 for Cons1 and the other for Cons2) accordingly.

I hope I have been clear enough, if not please forgive me and tell me if you need further info.

Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

EDIT: To answer Paul - There's only 1 entry for each month for each building, so it's not a problem. But thanks for noticing that! Also thanks a million to xQbert - your answer is exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks for your time man.

Comment: use max and a group by. similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263126/merging-two-rows-to-one-while-replacing-null-values

Comment: If there are multiple entries within one month - which one do you want to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we know that each record will have a null value using a max (or min) eliminates the null record values and combines the results into one row/record.

```
SELECT  Building,
        max(CASE 
            WHEN ReadingDate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
            THEN (EndMeter - StartMeter)
            ELSE NULL
        END)
    AS 'Cons1',
        max(CASE 
            WHEN ReadingDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 Year) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 Year) 
            THEN (EndMeter - StartMeter)
            ELSE NULL
        END)
    AS 'Cons2',
CONCAT(
        MONTHNAME (
            tblElectricReadings.ReadingDate
        )
    ) AS MonthRecorded
FROM    tblElectricReadings
WHERE   ReadingDate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
GROUP BY Building, CONCAT(MONTHNAME(tblElectricReadings.ReadingDate))
ORDER BY ReadingDate
```